# Why does R chloropeth map display as a square?

Tags: r, plotly, maps

I'm using R `plotly` (plotly_4.10.0) to create a chloropeth map of Europe. I'm using the R code present [here](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Ekelloggs/10/map-of-europe/#code).
My output plot is always in the shape of a square. I've marked the borders in red in the image to highlight the issue.

How do I increase the width of my plot to show all of Europe without zooming out? I tried the options `plot_ly(width = 800)` and `plot_ly(sizes = c(1, 600))` but that does not make a difference.

```
library(plotly)
trace1 <- list(
  geo = "geo", 
  type = "choropleth", 
  z = c("6", "4", "5"), 
  showscale = TRUE, 
  locationmode = "country names", 
  locations = c("Germany", "France", "Italy"), 
  autocolorscale = TRUE
)
data <- list(trace1)
layout <- list(
  geo = list(
    scope = "europe", 
    domain = list(
      x = c(0, 1), 
      y = c(0, 1)
    ), 
    lataxis = list(range = c(35.0, 70.0)), 
    lonaxis = list(range = c(-9.0, 38.0)), 
    showland = TRUE, 
    landcolor = "rgb(229, 229, 229)", 
    showframe = TRUE, 
    projection = list(type = "Mercator"), 
    resolution = 50, 
    countrycolor = "rgb(255, 0, 255)", 
    coastlinecolor = "rgb(0, 255, 255)", 
    showcoastlines = TRUE
  ), 
  title = "map of Europe", 
  legend = list(traceorder = "reversed")
)
p <- plot_ly()
p <- add_trace(p, geo=trace1$geo, type=trace1$type, z=trace1$z, showscale=trace1$showscale, locationmode=trace1$locationmode, locations=trace1$locations, autocolorscale=trace1$autocolorscale)
p <- layout(p, geo=layout$geo, title=layout$title, legend=layout$legend)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could play with the [`margin`](https://plotly.com/r/setting-graph-size/) like this:

```r
library(plotly)
trace1 <- list(
  geo = "geo", 
  type = "choropleth", 
  z = c("6", "4", "5"), 
  showscale = TRUE, 
  locationmode = "country names", 
  locations = c("Germany", "France", "Italy"), 
  autocolorscale = TRUE
)
data <- list(trace1)
layout <- list(
  geo = list(
    scope = "europe", 
    domain = list(
      x = c(0, 1), 
      y = c(0, 1)
    ), 
    lataxis = list(range = c(35.0, 70.0)), 
    lonaxis = list(range = c(-9.0, 38.0)), 
    showland = TRUE, 
    landcolor = "rgb(229, 229, 229)", 
    showframe = TRUE, 
    projection = list(type = "Mercator"), 
    resolution = 50, 
    countrycolor = "rgb(255, 0, 255)", 
    coastlinecolor = "rgb(0, 255, 255)", 
    showcoastlines = TRUE
  ), 
  title = "map of Europe", 
  legend = list(traceorder = "reversed")
)
m <- list(
  l = 200,
  r = 200,
  b = 50,
  t = 50,
  pad = 40
)
p <- plot_ly()
p <- add_trace(p, geo=trace1$geo, type=trace1$type, z=trace1$z, showscale=trace1$showscale, locationmode=trace1$locationmode, locations=trace1$locations, autocolorscale=trace1$autocolorscale)
p <- layout(p, geo=layout$geo, title=layout$title, legend=layout$legend,
            margin = m)
p
#> Warning: `marker.color` does not currently support multiple values.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>